# flot: show yaxis values

Tags: javascript, flot

I can not show values for yaxis and I do not understand

I have the values for :
data1 : 22, 000001115, 93, 0.000001137, 538, 0.000001003, 982, 0.000001004

my javascript function :

```
function Formatter(val, axis) {
 if ((val > 0.000001) && (val < 0.000002))  {

  return "<span >" +  val * 1000000  + "e-6</span>";
}
 else {
    return val.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals);
  }
```

}

the graph :

```
var placeholder = $("#flot-exemple-1");
 var options = {
    xaxis: {
        axisLabel: 'Temperature (C)',
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'verdana, sans-serif'
    },
    yaxis: {
        //scientific:TRUE,
        tickFormatter: Formatter,
```

**edit:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patker53/7ff8nyfp/5/)

Comment: any errors in the console? what is the complete json string?

Comment: I think that everything is correct. It works for large values , not for very small values..if ((val > 0.00001..is never executed..that is the problem

Comment: Try to build a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or code snippet which shows the problem.

Comment: You have these values: "22, 000001115, 93, 0.000001137" The first one is missing a decimal. Was this a typo or something in your actual code?

Comment: that is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/patker53/7ff8nyfp/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle the second part of the formatter function is not executed because the first part is always executed. Change the first if-clause to

```
if ((val >= 0.004) && (val < 0.04))
```

and then the second will be executed for your example data. (See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ff8nyfp/7/))